# My WordPress Custom Theme Does Not Get CSS Styles

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm learning how to make a WordPress theme from scratch & I'm facing a bad problem right now. The problem is that the CSS styles that I've added does not apply to the menu navigation of my theme.

Here's the `index.php` file:

```
    <?php 
get_header();

if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <h2><?php the_content(); ?></h2>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile;

    else:
        echo '<p>No content found!</p>';

    endif;

get_footer();
?>
```

Here's the `header.php` file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div class="container">
        <header class="site-header">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
            <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

            <nav class="site-nav">
                <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary'
                );
                ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

As you can see I added the css class **site-nav** to the  tag and then I coded this as css styles to it:

```
.site-nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after{content: "";display:table;}
.site-nav ul:after{clear:both;}
.site-nav ul{*zoom:1;}
.site-nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
```

But whenever I run the theme, I get this screen:

[image]

But note that I already have the `functions.php` which adds the CSS styles and I have added other CSS styles such as body or etc to it and it works but I don't why the menu navigation does not change !!

Here's the `functions.php`:

```
<?php 
function learningWordpress_resources(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','learningWordpress_resources');
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
));
?>
```

Here's the full CSS [code](http://www.paste.org/82432)

Comment: include css path in header and add all css in stylesheet file .it will work automatically

Comment: is style.css file placed in your theme folder??

Comment: please provide a functions.php

Comment: @Gulshan how to include css path in header

Comment: @pouhiocuprai first of all tell me structure of theme you added..

Comment: @pouhiocuprai add your all css in style.css which placed in your theme root folder

Comment: @Gulshan Its not problem

Comment: @pouhiocuprai i just add an answer.check if its working for you

Comment: @pouhiocuprai please got to theme and check is there menu option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide class

```
 <nav class="site-nav">
 <?php 
      $args = array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
       'menu_class'     => 'site_nav',
     );
   ?>
  <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

Goto check Css like this

```
#header .site-nav{} // container class
#header .site-nav ul {} // container class first unordered list
#header .site-nav ul ul {} //unordered list within an unordered list
#header .site-nav li {} // each navigation item
#header .site-nav li a {} // each navigation item anchor
#header .site-nav li ul {} // unordered list if there is drop down items
#header .site-nav li li {} // each drop down navigation item
#header .site-nav li li a {} // each drap down navigation item anchor
```

functions.php changes

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
    ));
}
   add_theme_support('menus');
```

Refer:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

Comment: did you get solution??